# Responsive Row Not Respecting Height Of DIVs inside it

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, height

I have three divs inside a 12 col div in a row with a min height set for the desktop view. When the viewer is narrowed, the surrounding div does not stretch to contain the now stacked divs. I know this must be a simple fix but my brain is fighting me! See the Fiddle below and thanks for your help!

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: yellow">

        <div style="min-height:200px">

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="background-color: red; margin:10px;">
                Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>
            </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="background-color: red; margin:10px;">
                Content2<br>Content22<br>Content2<br>Content2<br>
            </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="background-color: red; margin:10px;">
                Content3<br>Content3<br>Content3<br>Content3<br>
            </div>

        </div>


    </div>
</div>
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kylebellamy/ok696Lkw/2/)

Comment: Why do you have cols within a col ? and what is this div ? check this fiddle to see if it's what you are trying to do : http://jsfiddle.net/ok696Lkw/3/

Comment: The reason was for styling in the actual page that creates a box around the three with some js scripting so I needed them to be nest in that fashion. Thanks for the answer though, it did help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap columns make use of the `float` property and therefore are not counted as `block` elements.

To fix this issue, you need to add `overflow: auto` to the containing element like so:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: yellow">

        <div style="min-height:200px; overflow: auto;">

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="background-color: red; margin:10px;">
                Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>
            </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="background-color: red; margin:10px;">
                Content2<br>Content22<br>Content2<br>Content2<br>
            </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="background-color: red; margin:10px;">
                Content3<br>Content3<br>Content3<br>Content3<br>
            </div>

        </div>


    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ok696Lkw/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/ok696Lkw/4/

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: yellow">

        <div class="row">
            <div style="min-height:200px">

                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="background-color: red; margin:10px;">
                    Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="background-color: red; margin:10px;">
                    Content2<br>Content22<br>Content2<br>Content2<br>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="background-color: red; margin:10px;">
                    Content3<br>Content3<br>Content3<br>Content3<br>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: yellow">
        <div style="min-height:200px">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="background-color: red; margin:10px;">Content
                <br>Content
                <br>Content
                <br>Content
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="background-color: red; margin:10px;">Content2
                <br>Content22
                <br>Content2
                <br>Content2
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="background-color: red; margin:10px;">Content3
                <br>Content3
                <br>Content3
                <br>Content3
                <br>
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```